# Persisting specifications

Tags: c#, persistence, dsl, specification-pattern

I'm building a system where a user can subsribe for items and get periodically notifications for new items. **Users should define what items they want by filtering on certain properties.**

I'm using the specification pattern to filter items. My thought is that users should define their own specifications in a web gui.

The filtering is simply:

```
ItemService
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> GetMatching(IEnumerable<Item> items, IItemSpecification spec)
    {
        return items.Where(spec.IsMatch);
    }
}

IItemSpecification
{
    IsMatch(Item item);
}
```

The question is, what's the best way to persist eaach users different specifications? I don't have any requirements on how i persist it. Relational database, document databaes, xml, whatever works.

I can think of:

- Write a external DSL (and store it in a simple column in a rdb)
- Store a row (in a rdb) for each property in a specification, which indicates what to filter on and modifiers (equals, greater then). This will result in pretty many rows.
- Create a new table for each specification (don't know if this is realistic)

It seems that the DSL option is the cleanest solution (i only need to write a `DSLSpecification` which takes a dsl and pass it to my Itemservice.
Maybe i'm overcomplicating things.

Comment: if you are filtering your data in db and optimization is your main goal, you should use method 2 it's the easiest way to use it in db procedure to build dynamic query. if all the job is done in c# you should use DSL or just store is as an XML' serialized IItemSpecification object

Comment: @Silx All the filtering is done in c#. Storing my specs as xml may work. I just need a way to express all clauses as properties. Going to experiment with that. Thanks.